# How to upload to S3 using a custom Angular directive that fetches a file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3

So I'm using the following setup to allow a user to pick a file to upload via a custom Angular directive:

http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

I try to upload to Amazon S3 using the following AngularJS code in a controller method:

```
var formData = {
          'key': res.key,
          'policy': res.policy,
          'signature': res.signature,
          'acl': 'public-read',
          'success_action_status': '201',
          'AWSAccessKeyId': res.AWSAccessKeyId,
          'file': file
        };
        $http({
          url: formUrl,
          method: "POST",
          data: formData,
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(status);
          console.log(file.type);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('Error: ');
          console.log(data);
        });
```

Note that *file* in formData corresponds to the file uploaded via the custom directive in the jsfiddle.

After running the above POST request, the Chrome dev tools console shows a 400 error with message:

```
The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.
```

How do I fix this?  Do I need to convert the file to some other format?

Here is a sanitized copy of the formData parameters relevant for S3 shown in the console that I get back as part of the error ersponse:

```
AWSAccessKeyId: "AKXXDFDSFABGCADF7Q"
Acl: "public-read"
Success-Action-Status: "201"
key: "2020/blah_person_342_sy_18_"
policy: "eyJleHBpcmF0axxxxxxxx25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJzY2N0c2ktZGF0YW5leHVzLXN0YWdpbmcifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsIiJdLHsiYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSx7InN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3N0YXR1cyI6IjIwMSJ9LFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCIkcGVyc29uX2lkIiwiIl0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRzdXJ2ZXlfaWQiLCIixxxxxxxoIiwiJGF1dGhlbnRpY2l0eV90b2tlbiIsIiJdLFsiY29udXXYHC1sZW5ndxxxxxFuZ2UiLDAsNTAwMDAwMDBdXX0="
signature: "wwxxxxx5Uh+6kSuLF2xxxxujk=
```

Here is the 400 POST request header as copied from Chrome dev tools:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: sanitized.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Origin: http://localhost:3000
X-CSRF-Token: XXXSanitized==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
Referer: http://localhost:300/mypath
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3
```

Comment: Could be a weird character in the key, policy, signature, or access key ID that's messing up the value?

Comment: Posted a sanitized version above - Only *=* and *+* might be weird, but Amazon S3 usually has those....

Comment: can you post the full sanitized headers from the request?

Comment: as i'm unfamiliar with angular, what does `angular.identity` do and why do you need it?

Comment: @Derek, apparently angular's default transformRequest function will try to serialize the FormData object, so we override it with the identity function to leave the data intact.

Comment: I notice the Request payload is "[Object object]"